# My procedure gives error when I run

Tags: mysql

My procedure gives error when I run. I couldn't find where is mistake ?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE testing ()
  BEGIN
  DECLARE i INT;
  DECLARE vSite VARCHAR(100);
  set @i = 1;
  BEGIN WHILE @i <= 5 DO
      SET  @vSite = @vSite + CONCAT('LINE '+@i+', ');
     SET @i = @i + 1;
  END WHILE
        SELECT @vSite;
  END


/* Error 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT @vSite; END' at line 10
*/

/* required output given below

LINE 1, LINE 2, LINE 3, LINE 4, LINE 5,

 */
```

[image]

Comment: Read [for correct syntax of **while**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/while.html)

Comment: When i place sami colon in end while error resolved but not give correct output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved By My Self

```
  delimiter //
CREATE procedure while_examples()
wholeblock:BEGIN
  declare str VARCHAR(255) default '';
  declare x INT default 0;
  SET x = 1;

  WHILE x <= 5 DO
    SET str = CONCAT(str,'LINE',x,',');
    SET x = x + 1;
  END WHILE;

  select str;
END//
CALL while_examples();
```

[image]